# Adding country code constant to phone number input on form

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to add a permanent +234 to the phone number value before it is submitted into the database

I have tried to type (+234).('Alternate_Number) on the form page to see if it will pass the array into the database but it didnt work

```
<div class="form-group row">
                                        <label  class="col-sm-3 col-form-label" for="Alternate_PhoneNumber">Alternate PhoneNumber :</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-9">

                                            <input type="tel" name="Alternate_PhoneNumber" placeholder=" (08032xxxxxx)" class="Alternate_PhoneNumber form-control" id="Alternate_PhoneNumber" value="<?php echo set_value('Alternate_PhoneNumber', ''); ?>" minlength="11" maxlength="11">       
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

controller 
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('Alternate_PhoneNumber','Alternate PhoneNumber','|numeric|exact_length[11]|xss_clean');


 main model
  'Alternate_PhoneNumber'  => $this->input->post('Alternate_PhoneNumber'),
```

i want to just have the submitted value in the database to be +234 and the value submitted by the user like +2340834144706

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for your case?

```
'Alternate_PhoneNumber'  => '+234' . $this->input->post('Alternate_PhoneNumber'),
```

Comment: Thank you did work, but is there a way i can restrict users from inputing 0 as the first digit in phone number field

Comment: @user2943301 you don't really need to prevent them from inputting 0 as the first digit, you can strip it yourself. Have a look at [this](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dc8e101169073c2544fc66b4657c10172e1931b0)

Answer (score 1):

Use `concatenation` before saving data into database.

1) Suppose the variable `$PhoneNumber = '0834144706'` is your actual number.

2) And one more prefix variable called `$country_code = '+234'`;

3) Do `concatenation` like this (Full Code)

```
$PhoneNumber = '0834144706';
$country_code = '+234';
$final_number = $country_code.$PhoneNumber; // Has value +2340834144706
```

and save the `$final_number`variable data into database.